# How to use parameters in java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, parameters

I completed a simple string processing assignment using ArrayList. Now what I have to do is ask the user to input a parameter and then process the string (remove vowels, make everything lower case, etc). First I hard coded a string to make sure everything works, but now the user has to tell the program what string to process (The user would write this: java StringProcessing input.txt). I attempted to write the code for a parameter, but I am getting error messages.

here is the error:

```
StringProcessing.java:9: error: illegal start of type
} catch (Exception e) {
  ^
StringProcessing.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
    input.add(printStackTrace);
             ^
StringProcessing.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
    input.add(printStackTrace);
```

Code is below:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class StringProcessing {


    public static void main (String [] args) {

            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
            input.add(printStackTrace);

    //      input.add("ahHhdafsAhsopeifnlAshash339SNnadfnoaAhasdfhash3aash33hhnllashppeHhd3PPDDkashnbn4ijashonethelightalhnZZndaeJ");


            int index=0;
            int numberOfTimes=0;


              System.out.print(input.get(0).substring((input.get(0).length()/2),((input.get(0).length()+2)/2)));

           System.out.println("\n");

            for (int i=0; i<input.get(0).length(); i+=index) {
                  index = input.get(0).indexOf("ash");
                  if (index!=-1){
                          numberOfTimes+=1;
                  } else {
                         break;
                 }
           }

    System.out.print(numberOfTimes);
    System.out.println("\n");


    String vowel = input.get(0);
    vowel = vowel.replace("a","");

    vowel = vowel.replace("e","");

    vowel = vowel.replace("i","");

    vowel = vowel.replace("o","");

    vowel = vowel.replace("u","");

    input.add(vowel);




    String lower = input.get(0).toLowerCase();

    System.out.print(lower);
    System.out.print(input.get(1));


    }


    }
```

Comment: you have a catch block at the top of your main method but no try block..

Comment: What do you think `input.add(printStackTrace);` does?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it does. I've never learned parameters. I'm just trying to add the string that the user writes to the list.

Comment: can you post the error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably accidentally deleted something at some point right under your `main` method

```
try { // missing
   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Note that this only addresses the compilation error. You are still going to have other issues related to actually getting the user input. You are successfully opening a file (using parameters, ie: `args[0]`), but you will need to read the file and add the contents of the file into your `input` array list.